# AutoHotKey How can I connect dropdown list to my edit boxes here

Tags: autohotkey

I have tried everything for days now to fix this issue and I am so tired and need help, I want each number in the dropdown list to have its own load, for example DDL 1 should load independently all the edit boxes and DDL2 and so on.Each DDL should have its own Data loaded.. here is my code

```
`Gui 1:Font, S8 CDefault, Tahoma
Gui, Color, 008AB8
Gui 1:Show, x131 y91 h379 w479, Rotation Helper

Gui, Add, DropDownList,x76 y27 w50 h20 r10 gLoad, 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y57 w50 h20 vMyEdit,Hotkey
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y87 w50 h20 vMyEdit2,Color
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y117 w50 h20 vX1,X1
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y147 w50 h20 vY1,Y1
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y177 w50 h20 vX2,X2
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y207 w50 h20 vY2,Y2

Gui, Add,  Button, x366 y337 w90 h30 gLoad, Load
Gui, Add, Button, x256 y337 w100 h30 gSave, Save
Gui, Add, GroupBox, x6 y7 w450 h250 , Settings

Save:
Gui, Submit, NoHide

IniWrite,%MyEdit%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List, List1
IniWrite,%MyEdit2%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List, List2
IniWrite,%X1%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List, List3
IniWrite,%Y1%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List, List4
IniWrite,%X2%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List, List5
IniWrite,%Y1%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List, List6

return

Load:
GuiControl,, MyEdit, %Read% 
GuiControl,, MyEdit2, %Read2%
GuiControl,, X1, %newX1% 
GuiControl,, Y1, %newY1%
GuiControl,, X2, %newX2%
GuiControl,, Y2, %newY2%


Iniread, Read, %a_workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List, List1
Iniread,Read2, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List, List2
Iniread,newX1, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List, List3
Iniread,newY1, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List, List4
Iniread,newX2, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List, List5
Iniread,newY2, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List, List6





Return`
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the DDL value as parameter in the ini, `submit` the DDL value and read the data **before** you set it in `load`.

```
Gui, Color, 008AB8
Gui 1:Show, x131 y91 h379 w479, Rotation Helper

Gui, Add, DropDownList,x76 y27 w50 h20 r10 gLoad vDDL, 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y57 w50 h20 vMyEdit,Hotkey
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y87 w50 h20 vMyEdit2,Color
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y117 w50 h20 vX1,X1
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y147 w50 h20 vY1,Y1
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y177 w50 h20 vX2,X2
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y207 w50 h20 vY2,Y2

Gui, Add,  Button, x366 y337 w90 h30 gLoad, Load
Gui, Add, Button, x256 y337 w100 h30 gSave, Save
Gui, Add, GroupBox, x6 y7 w450 h250 , Settings

Save:
Gui, Submit, NoHide

IniWrite,%MyEdit%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List1
IniWrite,%MyEdit2%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List2
IniWrite,%X1%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List3
IniWrite,%Y1%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List4
IniWrite,%X2%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List5
IniWrite,%Y1%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List6

return

Load:
Gui, Submit, NoHide

Iniread, Read, %a_workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List1
Iniread,Read2, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List2
Iniread,newX1, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List3
Iniread,newY1, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List4
Iniread,newX2, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List5
Iniread,newY2, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List6

GuiControl,, MyEdit, %Read%
GuiControl,, MyEdit2, %Read2%
GuiControl,, X1, %newX1%
GuiControl,, Y1, %newY1%
GuiControl,, X2, %newX2%
GuiControl,, Y2, %newY2%
```

Comment: Thank you so much I owe you.